# SWF not showing on webpage

Tags: flash, video, embed

I imported a .flv video in Flash CS6, exported to .swf and it was ok.
But I needed to loop the video, so in the actions in Flash CS6 I wrote"

```
var myLis:Object = new Object;
myLis.complete = function(){
 flvPlayer.play();
}
flvPlayer.addEventListener("complete", myLis);
```

...exported to swf again and when I open the file on the PC with Flash Player 11 it is playing, but embeded to webpage it shows only while field.

Embed code:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"  codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab" width="498" height="380" id="test1"> 
 <param name="movie" value="banner1.swf" />
 <embed src="banner1.swf" width="498" height="380" name="test1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
```

This code works if there is no loop script, but do not work after I added the script to loop the video.

Answer (score 0):

I just found that the .SWF by default links to the .flv on the hard drive, but the link contains drive letter, parent dirs etc. So in Flash CS6 clicked on the video and changed the source link to a relative one - from "C:/folder/example.flv" to "example.flv". Uploaded both to the server and it is ok.